# Using case_when() within mutate() to create levels for a factor variable

Tags: r

I want to create a factor variable where all punctuations are properly labeled, and all characters are labeled as "char"

```
char <- read.xlsx("ccp35.xlsx", sheet="CCP")
chars <- tbl_df(char)
chars$punc <- chars %>%
    mutate(punc = case_when(
        chars$Character =="，" ~ "comma",
        chars$Character =="。"| "Character" =="？" ~ "stop"
        TRUE ~ "char"))
```

I've tried the code without the TRUE ~ "char" line, it worked nicely, with all character labeled as "NA".

But when I added the last line, there was an error:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"chars$Character =="。"| "Character" =="？" ~ "stop"
TRUE"
```

Comment: Please provide example data using `dput()`.

Comment: You are missing a comma after `"stop"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

1. You forgot a comma in your parameter list.
2. You accidentally put `Character` in quotes and treat it as a string — syntax highlighting offers a hint here.
3. `mutate` returns a tibble, you should assign it, for instance, to `chars`. Definitely not to `chars$punc`.
4. While not an error, the `chars$`s in your code are redundant.
5. I also suggest foregoing the intermediate variables with unclear names, and to use a pipeline for the complete expression instead.

This leaves us with:

```
chars <- read.xlsx("ccp35.xlsx", sheet="CCP") %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(
        punc = case_when(
            Character == "，" ~ "comma",
            Character == "。" | Character == "？" ~ "stop",
            TRUE ~ "char"
        )
    )
```

I also urge you to format code consistently, and to always put single spaces around infix operators (as done in my code).

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Both the code and suggestions are helpful!

Answer (score -1):

I don't have your data, but it seems that you forgot to add "chars$" before `"Character"=="？"`. Change the `chars$Character =="。"| "Character" =="？" ~ "stop"` with `chars$Character =="。" | chars$Character =="？" ~ "stop"` and see what happens.

Comment: No, that’s unnecessary.